# Does Kong Cloud support custom plugins?

Tags: gateway, api-gateway, kong, tyk, kong-plugin

Kong recently released a [cloud version](https://konghq.com/cloud/) of their service, but I can't find any good documentation on it.

My questions:

1. Is the service a pure SAAS, or do I still need to manage my own cloud infrastructure?
2. Can I install custom plugins?

Reason I'm asking is because I am also evaluation [Tyk cloud](https://tyk.io/api-gateway/cloud/#multi-cloud), and I want to know the difference between them.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about Kong Cloud - Not sure it is prod ready / Generally Available yet. No pricing info or ability to purchase kong cloud without speaking with their sales reps.

If you want custom plugins, Tyk does not allow this in their pure SaaS offering. But with Tyk Multi-Cloud https://tyk.io/api-gateway/cloud/#multi-cloud You can write your own custom plugins in Python, Lua, Javascript, or any language supporting gRPC.

The difference between Tyk Cloud and Tyk Multi-Cloud is that Multi-Cloud offers a hybrid cloud agnostic architecture allowing you to deploy your gateways in your own infrastructure (more secure & more performant close to your backend services), with the management layer offered as a SaaS. Tyk Cloud is a pure SaaS solution.